# RStudio Project stalls even without running anything

Tags: r, rstudio

One of my RStudio projects stalls even before I've run any code or loaded any packages or data. I can edit scripts but it won't save them and it won't run code in the console. I am still able to use R from the terminal. After some time (in the range of an hour or so), multiple dialog boxes will pop up with the message `Unable to establish connection with R session`. I've seen a similar thing before when loading big datasets or running something computationally intensive but never before I've even run any code or loaded any data.

My other Projects don't seem to have the same problem.

I've also filed an issue [here on the RStudio github](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1692) with some screenshots and log files in case that's helpful.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for the new website https://community.rstudio.com/.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update the `data.table` package. See the [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1692) I filed or this [thread on RStudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-v1-1-crashes-unable-to-establish-connection-with-r-session/2039)